# How to run a Proc within a dynamically generated module?

Tags: ruby, module, eval, block, dsl

It might sound confusing, but I'm working with a small team of newcomers, and I'm trying to abstract away some things in ruby to make things go more smoothly. The part I'm having problems with is namespaces.

Basically, namespaces with ruby can be created as:

```
module EIF
  module Core
    module Entities
    #stuff
    end
  end
end
```

or

```
module EIF
end

module EIF::Core
end

module EIF::Core::Entities
#some stuff
end
```

Thing is, this is honestly cumbersome. I wanted something akin to C# where you simply define the namespace as:

```
namespace EIF.Core.Entities
{
  #Some stuff
}
```

And be done with it. I managed to get something similar by using eval to create the modules (after matching the name to a regular expression)

```
def namespace(path)
  if path.match(/^([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)(::[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)*$/)
    spaces = path.split("::")
    code = ""
    spaces.each { |m| code << "module #{m}\n" }
    spaces.each { code << "end\n" }
    eval(code)
  else
    raise ArgumentError, "'#{path}' is not a valid namespace"
  end
end
```

The result is that I can now do the following:

```
namespace "EIF::Core::Entities"
class EIF::Core::Entities::Attirbute
  #class code
end
```

Now comes the next step. I want to use a ruby block to make things easier to read, so that it will look like:

```
namespace "EIF::Core::Entities" do
  class Attribute
    #class code
  end
end

myAttribute = EIF::Core::Entities::Attribute.new
```

The problem is that so far, the only method I have found to create the modules on runtime is with eval, and when I try to slip the code block into eval, the resulting class remains in the root namespace. I've tried instance_eval, module_eval, and class_eval, and none create the class within the modules for some reason.

Any way I can do this? I'd hate to give up now.

Comment: Why on __earth__ would you want to do something like this? It's better for your inexperienced teammates to learn the actual __ruby__ constructs and not some obscure syntactic "addons" you want to create

Comment: Because it's fun :D

Oh, and besides, it's a hobby project. The code is not intended to be reusable, and these people aren't programmers to begin with (yet). I wanted to simplify some things using DSL

Comment: No, burdening your newcomers by making them learn not-quite-Ruby is not fun and whoever gets stuck maintaining your code will hate you. Does your C code have `#define BEGIN {` and `#define END }` too?

Comment: This is the only thing I'm creating to make things easier (ruby is already easy). And no, no one will have to maintain this since it's an inconsequential rogue-like RPG. Calm down, you will not find this on the government servers or something. I'm not a programming course teacher either, so I'm not leading generations of people astray. I already explained to them what modules where, but some where having trouble understanding, and the code gets longer than necessary.

Comment: The original ruby constructs are concise enough and delightfully non-clever. If you don't like having deeply nested modules, avoid them another way. It isn't typically wise to have more than 2-3 levels anyways.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I wouldn't by any means use this in a production environment, since nesting modules only add two lines per module; it's inconsequential. That said, this is mostly an experiment, and if this makes our lives easier while they get a feeling of what programming is like in a more intuitive way, then all the better. Like I said, I'm not doing much, this is only to make working with multiple files less daunting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done.

It seems that when you add a class using module_eval, as in:

```
My::Namespace.module_eval do
  class MyClass
  end
end
```

The namespace for MyClass is resolved to :: regardless of the context. However, by writing:

```
class self::MyClass
```

The namespace is resolved to the current namespace object, thus the resulting class definition will be in My::Namespace

I don't know why this happens, but at least I got something working. Now the problem is that while this is shorter, the word self is counter-intuitive.